# How to use parameters from data frame in R and loop through time holding them constant

Tags: r, nested, time-series, lapply, sapply

I have a function (weisurv) that has 2 parameters - sc and shp.  It is a function through time (t). Time is a sequence, i.e. t<-seq(1:100).

```
weisurv<-function(t,sc,shp){
surv<-exp(-(t/sc)^shp)
return(surv)
}
```

I have a data frame (df) that contains a list of sc and shp values (like 300+ of them). For example, I have:

```
     M       shp     sc      p  C i
1    1  1.138131 10.592154 0.1  1 1
2 1.01  1.143798 10.313217 0.1  1 2
3 1.02  1.160653 10.207863 0.1  1 3
4 1.03  1.185886  9.861997 0.1  1 4
...
```

I want to apply each set (ROW) of sc and shp parameters to my function. So the function would look like weisurv(t,sc[[i]],shp[i]]) for each row[i].  I do not understand how to use apply or adply to do this though I'm sure one of these or a combo of both are what is needed. 
In the end, I am looking for a data frame that gives a value of weisurv for each time given a set of sc and shp (held constant through time).  So if I had 10 sets of sc and shp parameters, I would end up with 10 time series of weisurv. 
Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using plyr:

As a matrix (time in cols, rows corresponding to rows of df):

```
aaply(df, 1, function(x) weisurv(t, x$sc, x$shp), .expand = FALSE)
```

As a list:

```
alply(df, 1, function(x) weisurv(t, x$sc, x$shp))
```

As a data frame (structure as per matrix above):

```
adply(df, 1, function(x) setNames(weisurv(t, x$sc, x$shp), t))
```

As a long data frame (one row per t/sc/shp combination); note uses mutate and the pipe operator from `dplyr`):

```
newDf <- data.frame(t = rep(t, nrow(df)), sc = df$sc, shp = df$shp) %>%
  mutate(surv = weisurv(t, sc, shp))
```

You can also create a wide data.frame and then use `reshape2::melt` to reformat as long:

```
wideDf <- adply(df, 1, function(x) setNames(weisurv(t, x$sc, x$shp), t))
newDf <- melt(wideDf, id.vars = colnames(df), variable.name = "t", value.name = "surv")
newDf$t <- as.numeric(as.character(newDf$t))
```

Pretty plot of last newDf (using ggplot2):

```
ggplot(newDf, aes(x = t, y = surv, col = sprintf("sc = %0.3f, shp = %0.3f", sc, shp))) +
geom_line() +
scale_color_discrete(name = "Parameters")
```

[image: ggplot image of weisurv output]

Comment: thanks for showing me all the different potential uses from plyr.  on the long dataframe option, i get an error, possibly bc of %>%.  I like the adply option best but i'm not familiar enough with ggplot2 to be able to plot it!

Comment: I'm using the pipe operator from magrittr (or dplyr). If you've not got those packages installed, you need to do `install.packages("magrittr")` and then `library("magrittr")`. I'll add a version above which doesn't use the piper operator too.

Comment: thanks for posting an alternate.  is there any advantage to the long data frame approach? i ran the adply df option in about 2 minutes, however the long data frame option is still running 10+ minutes.  btw: i did install magrittr.

Comment: Depends on what format output you want. Added example to show reshaping between wide and long.

Comment: No worries. Just realised I overlooked something for the original long option. I've changed it to use mutate from dplyr - should be much, much quicker. You'll need to install dplyr if you haven't already.

Comment: Okay great.  I have a very related question in trying to do a similar operation - figured maybe I could ask you directly. I'm pretty sure it is super easy but I continue to get errors as I change the syntax. Given the same df as the example here, I simply want to apply a function and add a column with the result.  I tried adply and ddply: df$newcol<-ddply(df,.(p,Cv,M),function(x) T1(x$p,x$Cv,x$M,5000))   Note that T1 works fine.  Do you see anything wrong with this? I have also tried: adply(df,1,function(x) T1(x$p,x$Cv,x$M,5000))

Comment: The output from adply and ddply is a data.frame. You probably want to use aaply and the .expand FALSE parameter which if T returns a scalar will return a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the exact structure you want in the final dataframe...
and I think there must be a cleaner way to do this, but this should work.

**option 1**
rows are the same as your df, with new columns `t<n>` for each value of `t`:

```
for(n in t){
    df$temp <- weisurv(n, df$sc, df$shp)
    names(df)[n+2] <- paste0('t', n)
}
```

**option 2**
long dataframe, with columns `sc`, `shp`, `t`, and `weisurv(t,sc,shp)`:

```
l = length(t)
newdf <- data.frame(sc=rep(df$sc, each=l), shp=rep(df$shp, each=l),
    t=rep(t, times=nrow(df)) )
newdf$weisurv <- weisurv(newdf$t, newdf$sc, newdf$shp)
```